# Are these good examples of functions that do one thing only or am I getting a little carried away?

Tags: vba

I'm reading Robert C. Martin's "Clean Code" and for the past few days I've been fiddling with its function writing guidelines. At first I thought the idea of functions being two/three lines long to be ludicrous, but I'm slowly getting the hang of it. The problem is, I'm pretty sure I'm overdoing it now.

These are the first lines of the module I decided to refactor using the advice from the book.

```
Public Sub ExportAvailabilityData()
  Dim aplicativo As Excel.Application
  Set aplicativo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  aplicativo.Visible = True

  Dim pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook
  Set pastaDeTrabalho = aplicativo.Workbooks.Add

  Do Until pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets.Count = DaysInMonth(Month(Date)) + 1
    pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets.Add
  Loop

  Dim day As Integer
  For day = 1 To DaysInMonth(Month(Date))
    pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets(day).Name = Format(day, "00") & "." & Format(Month(Date), "00")
  Next day

  pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets(DaysInMonth(Month(Date)) + 1).Name = "Summary " & UCase(MonthName(Month(Date)))
End Sub

Private Function DaysInMonth(ByVal month As Integer) As Integer
  DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), month + 1, 1) - 1)
End Function
```

And this is how it looks like today.

```
Public Sub ExportAvailabilityData()
  Dim aplicativo As Excel.Application
  Set aplicativo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  aplicativo.Visible = True

  Dim pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook
  Set pastaDeTrabalho = aplicativo.Workbooks.Add

  CreateSheets pastaDeTrabalho
  NameSheets pastaDeTrabalho
End Sub

Private Sub CreateSheets(ByRef pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook)
  CreateDailySheets pastaDeTrabalho, Month(Date)
  CreateSummarySheet pastaDeTrabalho
End Sub

Private Sub CreateDailySheets(ByRef pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook, ByVal month As Integer)
  Do Until pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets.Count = DaysInMonth(month)
    pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets.Add
  Loop
End Sub

Private Sub CreateSummarySheet(ByRef pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook)
  pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets.Add
End Sub

Private Function DaysInMonth(ByVal month As Integer) As Integer
  DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), month + 1, 1) - 1)
End Function

Private Sub NameSheets(ByRef pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook)
  NameDailySheets pastaDeTrabalho, Month(Date)
  NameSummarySheet pastaDeTrabalho, Month(Date)
End Sub

Private Sub NameDailySheets(ByRef pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook, ByVal month As Integer)
  Dim day As Integer
  For day = 1 To DaysInMonth(month)
    pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets(day).Name = AssembleDailySheetName(day, month)
  Next day
End Sub

Private Sub NameSummarySheet(ByRef pastaDeTrabalho As Excel.Workbook, ByVal month As Integer)
  Dim index As Integer
  index = GetSummarySheetIndex(month)
  pastaDeTrabalho.Sheets(index).Name = AssembleSummarySheetName(month)
End Sub

Private Function GetSummarySheetIndex(ByVal month As Integer) As Integer
  GetSummarySheetIndex = DaysInMonth(month) + 1
End Function

Private Function AssembleDailySheetName(ByVal day As Integer, ByVal month As Integer) As String
  AssembleDailySheetName = Format(day, "00") & "." & Format(month, "00")
End Function

Private Function AssembleSummarySheetName(ByVal month As Integer) As String
  AssembleSummarySheetName = "Summary " & UCase(MonthName(month))
End Function
```

When I considered replacing the `"."` constant inside `AssembleDailySheetName()` with a call to yet another function (`GetDateSeparator()` or something similar), I decided to stop and get some feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem with breaking down a simple function like this is that it becomes too difficult to read. This is a simple function that creates a sheet for every day of the month. But to understand how it works, I have to trace through all these procedures.

Consider this rewrite:

```
Public Sub ExportAvailabilityData()

    Dim pastaDeTrabalho As Workbook
    Dim dtDay As Date

    Const sFMTDAY As String = "dd.mm"
    Const sFMTMONTH As String = "mmmm"
    Const sSUMMPREFIX As String = "Summary"

    Set pastaDeTrabalho = Workbooks.Add

    For dtDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), month(Date), 1) To DateSerial(Year(Date), month(Date) + 1, 0)
        pastaDeTrabalho.Worksheets.Add.Name = Format(dtDay, sFMTDAY)
    Next dtDay

    pastaDeTrabalho.Worksheets.Add.Name = sSUMMPREFIX & Space(1) & UCase(Format(Date, sFMTMONTH))

End Sub
```

Outside of declaration lines, this is five lines long. It only takes a few seconds to identify what the three sections do.

The other thing I would change is the name of the procedure. This procedure doesn't export anything. It should be named CreateMonthlyWorkbook() or something like that.

Comment: I've omitted the code that does the exporting because I haven't refactored it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the VBA tips! I had no idea `DateSerial(year, month, 0)` returned the last day of the previous `month`. And like Joe F suggested and your code demonstrates, adding a sheet and naming it immediately is the right way to go.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have definitely taken it in the right direction. Excellent work!

I don't see any compelling reason to break `AssembleDailySheetName()` down any further.

My only complaint is that I don't really like the separation of adding and naming the sheets. I see both steps as being part of creating a sheet. I think it would be nice to set the name of the sheet immediately after adding it (in the same function). That will likely eliminate some code as well. I suspect `Sheets.Add` may return the new sheet. If that's the case, there would be no need to look up the sheet by index to name it.

Comment: I'm automating something a colleague of mine used to do manually, so I've ordered the steps exactly like he did. That's why adding and naming are handled separately, I'm kind of stuck in his way of doing the task. To be honest, the idea of keeping addition and naming of sheets close together never crossed my mind. I'll definitely experiment with it, since I have lots of modules that do similar things. Thanks for the feedback.